# MS Access vba Password protect word doc

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I have the following code (copied from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/document-password-property-word?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to prevent a Word document being opened without a password. However, it does not work and I can just open the word doc as normal. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please.

```
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:="C:\FLS\Leads " & strDate & ".doc")
WordDoc.Password = strPassword
WordDoc.Save
WordDoc.Close
```

Comment: Apologies. The code works for me. I tested both docx and doc file formats. Which version of Word is involved? Is there anything special about the document? If, instead, you use the SaveAs method and specify the `WritePassword` parameter does that make a difference?

Comment: It is word 2010. I have done the same thing with an Excel spreadsheet with this code:     Set wkb = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\FLS\Excel Version " & 
    strDate & ".xls")
    wkb.Password = strpassword
    wkb.Save
    wkb.Close which works fine

Comment: There is nothing special about the document but the saveas with the writepassword parameter doesn't make any difference

Comment: Are you able to open the document as a user, go to File/Info. Under "Permissions"/Protect Document choose "Encrypt with password" and enter a password (case-sensitive!) - you'll be prompted twice. Save. Close. Open. All as a user, without code.

Comment: Yes I have just done that. File/Info Encrypt with password, entered it twice and saved and closed. But it still opens without requesting a password.I am totally confused as to why it is not working. When you save the document it says encrypted with a password under permissions but when you reopen it it says anyone can open and read this document.

Comment: The only thing I can find is that at the top of the document it says Compatibility Mode and I don't know why, I assume it is because it is .doc and not .docx. I am using .doc as some recipients have old versions.

Comment: How about a new document? My next steps would be: start Word in "Safe Mode"  (hold down Ctrl when starting it) to see if it works, then. And after that, restart Windows...

Comment: As I mentioned, I did test with *.doc and it did work. People with older versions (back through 2000,. I think) should have updated with a converter that allows them to read and write docx. But that's just FYI, I don't think that's this problem.